# Unable to extract value of key from a json file using jq on windows 64 bit OS

Tags: json, windows, jq

My `json` file is as follows

```
{ 
"Mappings" : {
 "RegionMap" : {
   "us-east-1"      : { "AMI" : "xxxxxx" },
   "us-east-2"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "us-west-1"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "us-west-2"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ca-central-1"   : { "AMI" : "" },
   "eu-central-1"   : { "AMI" : "" },
   "eu-west-1"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "eu-west-2"      : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-south-1"     : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-southeast-1" : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-southeast-2" : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-northeast-1" : { "AMI" : "" },
   "ap-northeast-2" : { "AMI" : "" },
   "sa-east-1"      : { "AMI" : "" }       
   }
  }
 }
```

I am trying to extract the value of `us-east-1` key. In the [jq playground](https://jqplay.org/), I was able to extract the value using the the following `filter`

```
.Mappings.RegionMap."us-east-1".AMI
```

But when try to run this filter using [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation#windows-with-choco) on my windows machine using the `command prompt`

```
 jq '.Mappings.RegionMap."us-east-1".AMI' <filename>
```

I am getting this `error`

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected INVALID_CHARACTER, expecting 
$end (Windows cmd shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
'.Mappings.RegionMap.us-east-1.AMI'
'jq: 1 compile error
```

I am using `jq version 1.5` on `Windows` Machine which has `64 bit OS`.

Can somebody let me know as to what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error text says, you are running into Windows cmd shell quoting issues.  When you get such an error message, try echoing your command line (minus any redirections).

One workaround is to put the jq command text into a file, and invoke jq with the -f option.

If you want to avoid the -f option, try something like:

```
jq ".Mappings.RegionMap.\"us-east-1\".AMI"
```

(For older versions of jq: jq ".Mappings.RegionMap | .[\"us-east-1\"].AMI" )